# How to present an Unlike link for a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a Facebook app which is interested in whether users like or unlike specific pages.  I want to offer a link to unlike a page, as so far as I know there is no way to unlike a page programmatically using the Graph API.

Facebook provide a like button, but (again, so far as I know) no unlike button.  How can I present an option to unlike a page without saying "Click here to go to the page, scroll down to the miniscule unlike link and click it"?

Comment: The answer below doesn't seem to work.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can issue a DELETE request to the page_id
suppose the page id is 1234567890123
place the link as on the a page as:

```
<a href="unlike.php?d=1234567890123">Unlike</a>
```

Now collect the GET parameter in the unlike.php file and fire a DELETE request through the graph api:

```
<?php
$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => FB_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
    'cookie' => true
));

$session = $fb->getSession();

if (empty($session))
{
    $loginUrl = $fb->getLoginUrl();
    echo "<script>window.top.location='{$loginUrl}';</script>";
    exit;
}

$fb_liked_page = $_GET['d']; //COLLECT THE PAGE ID HERE

try
{
    $status = $fb->api("/{$fb_liked_page}/likes", 'DELETE');

    if ($status)
    {
        echo "Success, Unliked!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Could not unlike this page.";
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that.  Is it possible to add likes using a similar method?

Comment: Are you sure this works?  I get "App must be on whitelist", and http://www.insidefacebook.com/2010/10/08/causes-whitelisted-like-pages-2/ suggests that Causes is the only app allowed to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Freak oops, forgot to notify you.